# How to keep MPI and non-MPI version?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Let's consider a program, as follows,

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int num_proc;
#ifdef MPI_VERSION
  MPI_init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_proc);
  MPI_Finalize();
#else
  num_proc = 1;
#endif

  printf("%d\n", num_proc);
}
```

I want to make it to be both MPI or non-MPI version.
That means when compiling and runing it without MPI linker, like below, num_proc is set to 1.

```
g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
```

While, if it is compiled and run with MPI linker, as below, num_proc is set to 2.

```
mpicxx main.cpp && mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: the MPI wrappers do not define any macro by default, so it is up to you to choose one and manually define it (or not) on your command line. Note you should not `#include <mpi.h>` when building a non MPI version (since you cannot assume `g++` will find it in its search path(.

Comment: an other option is to build the non-MPI version with a stub MPI library. For example, LAMMPS does that (see https://github.com/lammps/lammps/tree/master/src/STUBS)

Comment: In the same spirit as the stub MPI library, but perhaps better in a software engineering sense, is to write your own functions. For example, have a function called "start_parallel(&size, &rank)". You implement this in two versions in different files: one for serial, one for parallel. In parallel you call MPI_Init(), MPI_Comm_size() and MPI_Comm_rank(); for the serial version, set size = 1 and rank = 0. This means you can compile the serial version in the absence of an MPI library. It also means that your main code is identical for the serial and parallel versions.